# Is DB link from Oracle 19c to Oracle 10g database will work?

Tags: dblink, oracle19c

Is it possible to access a table in an Oracle 10g database using DB from an Oracle 19c database?

Answer (score 2):

Per [MOS Doc ID 207303.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=379785592932459&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=BULLETIN&id=207303.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=14sw0yjkvk_4), connections between those versions are not supported. The oldest version that 19c can connect with is 11.2. Based on other comments I have seen, some people *have* gotten it to work with 10g, but it should not be used in a production environment without full support, as results are not guaranteed or predictable.